# Steps to create a heuristic for solving a problem

Tags: algorithms, artificial-intelligence, heuristics, search

I am completely new to AI and doing self-learning to acquire this knowledge.
I went through the different available search algorithm like BFS, DFS and A* but something that I can't understand is a heuristic function that needs to be embedded in these algorithms. I am fine with algorithms but I don't know how we find a good heuristic function for every problem. Is there any steps that needs to be take to achieve a heuristic?

Any comment would greatly appreciated.

Comment: BFS and DFS use no heuristic, it's only A*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general method. Like all mathematics, algorithm design, programming, etc., coming up with heuristics is a creative act which requires you to use your intelligence and understanding of the problem domain.